# android Mediaplayer not playing too fast

Tags: android, media-player

I have a MediaPlayer object through which i am playing a sound on click of a button.the sound file is 1-2 second long only.When i am clicking the corresponding button one after another(quickly), it's not playing the sound twice(it is playing just once.I tried with some code like this :

```
public void onClick(View view) {
if(DrawSound.isPlaying()) {
          DrawSound.stop();
         DrawSound.prepareAsync();
        }
      DrawSound.start();
}
```

it's not wokring.Search a lot, but could make it work.Any help!!!!

Comment: what is DrawSound and what is slotDrawSound?

Comment: @Deva they are same.Sorry i edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys if someone can get help from this:

just solve my problem with a trick(after all trick can do all :p)

i took 2 MediaPlayer object and one MediaPlayer reference and wrote like this :

```
soundPlayer = DrawSound.isPlaying() ? DrawSound1 : DrawSound;
soundPlayer.start();
```

Comment: you can also do it with only one object.

Comment: oh really ? how can i do this only with one object ?

Comment: that is not working.Either you are not trying else you are clicking buttons too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using prepare instead of prepareAsync

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not releasing media player after its completed playing your sound ... use `release` and `reset` method in Media Players `setOnCompletionListener` Method...

you can use it like this ...

```
    if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                    try {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.reset();
                        mp.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                mp.start();
}
```

or you can use it ...

```
            mp.stop();         
            mp.prepareAsync();  
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start(); 
                }
            });
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: i use release then i used reset iyt is showing illegalargument exception.

Comment: do not release it if you want to use it again the same MediaPlayer Object just use reset().

Comment: after prepare it is useless to again set the datasource.do you understand the concept?

Comment: That was my mistake ... setting data Source and after that calling prepare(). i think you got it what to do ..

Comment: put the debug point in onClick method ... tell me whats going on there.

Comment: it's coming inside onClick method and everything is fine just the stuff i am tryin gto is not woriking.

Answer (score -1):

Try this and see if it works:

```
if(DrawSound.isPlaying()) {         
            DrawSound.stop();         
            DrawSound.prepareAsync();  
            DrawSound.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    DrawSound.start(); 
                }
            });
            }
```

Comment: throwing IllegalArgument Exception.

Comment: please edit ur question and put all the relevant code with the logcat